# running script from remote server from keyboard shortcut in phpstorm

Tags: php, ssh, phpstorm

Usually when I develop my application (php cli script but can by any command based script) I have another window open where I keep opened ssh connection (putty software for example).

When I save modified file in phpstorm (editor) I go to that other window and run a command to see my changes.

Is there a way in phpstorm to create a keyboard shortcut that when I press it would create a remote connection and execute my script in the same phpstorm window that I am working in? Also when I press that keyboard shortcut next time I dont want to create a ssh connection again but only execute scrip?

Do I need to create a macro on ssh session in phpstorm tools window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `Settings | Remote SSH External Tools`. If you do not have it -- make sure that `SSH Remote Run` plugin is installed and enabled.
2. Create your external tool (a command that will be executed remotely)
3. Assign any shortcut you want to that newly created entry in `Settings | Keymap | Remote External Tools`